# How to download file in angular in exact extension

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework

I want to download a file from the server through HTML tag using hardcord

**status.html**

```
<ion-col size="2" style="border-right:none;" >

 <ng-container *ngFor="let doc of document; ">

  <a href="http://myinnovativetest.com/CR/uploads/{{doc}}" 


(click)="download(doc)"  download>

  {{doc}}

</a><br />
      </ng-container>
```

**file.service.ts**

```
downloadFile(): Observable<any>{        

return this.http.get('http://myinnovativetest.com/CR/uploads', { 

responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob });

  }
```

**status.ts**

```
download(doc){
  this.fileService.downloadFile().subscribe(response => {

window.location.href = response.url;

 console.log(response.url)

 }), error => console.log('Error downloading the file'),

 () => console.info('File downloaded successfully');

//console.log("hello")
}
```

I expected to download file download.jpg but it download as  download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [File-Saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

`import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';`

```
download(doc) {
    this.fileService.downloadFile().subscribe(response => {

      FileSaver.saveAs(response, "data.pdf");

    }), error => console.log('Error downloading the file'),

      () => console.info('File downloaded successfully');

  }
```